# How to output the sum of specific rows from one data frame to a new column in another data frame?

Tags: r

I would ultimately like to have df2 with certain dates and the cumulative sum of values connected to those date ranges from df1.

```
df1 = data.frame("date"=c("10/01/2020","10/02/2020","10/03/2020","10/04/2020","10/05/2020",
                          "10/06/2020","10/07/2020","10/08/2020","10/09/2020","10/10/2020"),
                 "value"=c(1:10))
df1
```

```
> df1
   date       value
1  10/01/2020     1
2  10/02/2020     2
3  10/03/2020     3
4  10/04/2020     4
5  10/05/2020     5
6  10/06/2020     6
7  10/07/2020     7
8  10/08/2020     8
9  10/09/2020     9
10 10/10/2020    10
```

```
df2 = data.frame("date"=c("10/05/2020","10/10/2020"))
df2
```

```
> df2
  date
1 10/05/2020
2 10/10/2020
```

I realize this is incorrect, but I am not sure how to define df2$value as the sums of certain df1$value rows:

```
df2$value = filter(df1, c(sum(1:5),sum(6:10)))
df2
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
> df2
   date       value
1  10/05/2020    15
2  10/10/2020    40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another approach using `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>%
  mutate(date = if_else(date == "2020-05-10" |
                      date == "2020-10-10", date, NA_Date_)) %>% 
  fill(date, .direction = "up") %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value))
```

```
  date       value
  <date>     <int>
1 2020-05-10    15
2 2020-10-10    40
```

Answer (score 3):

We may use a non-equi join after converting the 'date' columns to `Date` class

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, date := mdy(date)]
setDT(df2)[, date := mdy(date)]
df2[, start_date := fcoalesce(shift(date) + days(1), floor_date(date, 'month'))]

df1[df2,.(value = sum(value)), on = .( date >= start_date, 
      date <= date), by = .EACHI][, -1, with = FALSE]
         date value
       <Date> <int>
1: 2020-10-05    15
2: 2020-10-10    40
```

---

Or another option is creating a group with `findInterval` and then do the group by `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(grp = findInterval(date, df2$date, left.open = TRUE)) %>% 
  summarise(date = last(date), value = sum(value)) %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  date       value
  <date>     <int>
1 2020-10-05    15
2 2020-10-10    40
```